# Stretch responsive image slider/carousel to full page width?

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, carousel

I am trying to figure out how I can stretch my slider image to the full-page width, but have it also be responsive. I am running on Wordpress and I'm not opposed to using Javascript if necessary. Here is the site: http://cmattayers.com/b2bu/

This is my original mockup, if that helps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaOcW.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Pull the slider div at the end but inside  just before last `</div>` of `<div class="navbar-header">` it may be found in your `header.php` if you use a shortcode like `[yourslidershortcode]` in your page content you have to modify it before post into direct theme `header.php` put  `<?php echo do_shortcode( '[yourslidershortcode]' ); ?>`

**I found the in the site you mentioned**

```
<div class="navbar-header">


 </div><!-- end of #logo -->
 <?php echo do_shortcode( '[yourslidershortcode]' ); ?>
</div>
```

If the slider show only on home page use below code instead of above

```
<div class="navbar-header">
</div><!-- end of #logo -->    
<?php
if ( is_home() ) {
  echo do_shortcode( '[yourslidershortcode]' ); 
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: That sort of worked, except it added the slider to every page on the website. I had to insert it further down than you suggested to get it outside the footer. There's also a lot of weird spacing and something seems to be applying a forced min-width to it. I'm not sure what.

Comment: Do you want to put the slider in home page only?